# Can't create Excel spreadsheet from Word

Tags: excel, vba, ms-word, export

I'm trying to write a VBA macro from within Word to create an Excel spreadsheet and export data to it. I'm having trouble just creating the new spreadsheet. For the following macro, I get "Object doesn't support this property or method" on the line

```
Set myWb = myExcel.Workbooks.Add
```

in the code

```
Private Sub CreateExcel2()

Dim myExcel As Object
Dim myWb As Object

Set myExcel = CreateObject("Excel.Application")
Set myWb = myExcel.Workbooks.Add

Application.DisplayAlerts = False

myWb.SaveAs FileName:="D:\test\dump.xls"

Application.DisplayAlerts = True

myWb.Close False
Set myWb = Nothing
myExcel.Quit
Set myExcel = Nothing

End Sub
```

Comment: Unable to reproduce

Comment: I couldn't reproduce this either. This isn't the *Mac* version of Word/Excel?

After your "Set myExcel" line, try 

If (myExcel Is Nothing) Then MsgBox "couldn't create an Excel object"

If you see the MsgBox, it means that the CreateObject didn't work (and for whatever reasons, that didn't raise an error)

Comment: I am trying this on a Mac at the moment. I may switch to the Windows laptop and compare behavior.

Comment: I do see it open the Excel application on the line Set myExcel = CreateObject("Excel.Application"). It just fails if I try a .Add or .Open on the myExcel object.

Comment: Ok, it works under Windows, so my problem is only with the Mac.

Comment: It's less important for me to be able to run this on a Mac, but it would be nice to have the option. In the meantime, I'll continue with Windows.

Answer (score 0):

You can try:

```
  On Error Resume Next
Set oExcel = GetObject(, "Excel.Application")
    If Err.Number <> 0 Then
        Err.Clear
        Set oExcel = CreateObject("Excel.Application")
     End If
On Error GoTo 0

oExcel.visible = true 'to check of excel opens
```

'try Set myWb = myExcel.Workbooks.Add()
'try Set myWb = oExcel.Workbooks.Open(sPathFile)

Comment: The Excel application opens ok, but it just doesn't seem to support .Add or .Open after that.

Comment: The problem only happens on the Mac. Not on Windows.